# PHP remove all html tags and keep plain text with DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, yii2

I am trying to find the best way to strip all the html tags from a string to keep only plain text. Now the easiest way ofcourse would be `strip_tags`, however it is not optimal since it will not work well with broken tags and etc.. I think that what i need is a DOM Parser. However I have no clue how this thing works.

For example i have a simple string:

```
    <p>
        <strong>​
            Some plain text
        </strong>
    </p>
```

I want to strip all the tags with DOM parser and keep the plain text:

```
Some plain text
```

How can i do that? I tried to use removeChild but it removes everything even the text:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($translation->text);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("*") as $tag) {
    $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
};
```

Comment: `$dom->textContent` ... you might want to trim the value because it keeps original inter-element whitespace in place.

Comment: Use php strip_tags function http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<?php

$content = <<<EOM
  <p>
    <strong>
      Some plain text
    </strong>
  </p>
EOM;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

echo trim($dom->textContent);
```

Or, simply, using `strip_tags`, you can do it.

```
<?php

$content = <<<EOM
  <p>
    <strong>
      Some plain text
    </strong>
  </p>
EOM;

echo trim(strip_tags($content));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function easy and fast:

```
function fetch_string($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@si', '', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content);
    $content = trim($content);
    return $content;
}
```

usage:

```
$string = '<p><strong>​Some plain text</strong></p>';
$output = fetch_string($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlPurifier for this. Try:

```
echo yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($html);
```

For more info check this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-htmlpurifier.html).